# Questions about using survey files, Ground Control Points and Checkpoints in Autodesk Forge Reality Capture

Tags: autodesk-forge, coordinate-systems, autodesk-realitycapture

**My use of Autodesk Forge Reality Capture**

I am using **Autodesk Forge Reality Capture** to create precise 3D models of **small target objects.** These models are then further adjusted in CAD, for eventual **3D printing.**

**MY GOAL:** I am trying to improve the precision of my 3D models **by providing a survey file with known markers (GCPs) positions** and I have consulted the API documents [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/).

**My Questions:**

1. *Which **coordinate system string** to specify* given my (*non*-geographical) arbitrary origin imaging application?
2. Is there is a way to provide **cartesian coordinates** locations in the **< gpc > tag,** and if so, *what is the syntax?*
3. When I should define a location as a **GPC point** and when I should define a location as a "**checkpoint**"?

**My Motivation for providing survey file to Forge**

Without providing survey information, I am finding that the resulting **Forge models are significantly distorted**, even when I use *images that provided good models previously with RECAP.*

When I previously modeled with the RECAP software, I initially had similarly distorted models until I provided RECAP with my marker positions.  After I provided precise marker positions to RECAP, I got excellent models.

*So I expect that if I can provide the marker locations to Forge I will again get very accurate output models.*

However, because my application is **not geographical**, I want to provide my marker positions to Forge in terms of either **spherical coordinates** or c**artesian coordinates** *from my own arbitrarily defined origin point.*

I can provide **distances in millimeters**, and **angles in degrees**.

I can't figure out from the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST/) which **coordinate system name** to provide.

I believe that I could probably provide the *spherical coordinates* from my arbitrary origin in the **< gcp > tag**, if I knew *which coordinate system is appropriate* for **altitudes measured in millimeters.** 
But I can't determine which *coordinate system string* I need to provide.

I see the very lengthy list of known coordinate system strings referred to in the documentation,  but they are just labels with no explanation of what they are.

I can provide **cartesian coordinates**, but I don't know which *coordinate system string* would be appropriate for that.  And even if I did, the **< gcp > tags** in the example don't illustrate any **x= y= z= format.**

***Can someone provide me more information on use of survey files for my application?***

**About my set up**

I have *more than 20 images* from *known vantage points* all around a *controlled target imaging zone.*

All around the target zone I have *fiduciary marker points*, with *at least 3 markers visible* in each image, and **frequently more.**

For every marker I know *which images that marker appears in*, and at which *xpixel and ypixel location* it is centered.

*BTW, in RECAP these locations were defined in terms of % of the frame, rather than pixel positions. That enables more precision than a single pixel.  **Is that no longer possible?***

I also know **the physical location of each marker in 3-space**, r*elative to an arbitrary origin (0,0,0) at the center of my imaging zone.*  I have these locations in terms of cartesian coordinates in millimeters, as well as in spherical coordinates forms.

Comment: I'm afraid that - based on the [docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/file-POST) - only geo coordinates are supported at the moment. But let me reach out to the dev team to confirm that.

Comment: Petr Broz - thank you.  I would reach out to them my selves if I knew a way to do so other than ask questions here.

Comment: No problem, I just heard back from the dev team. Let me post their feedback as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

GCP (Ground control points) and check points can be specified in Cartesian coordinates with an arbitrary origin by setting the value of the `coordinatesystem` attribute to `XYZ` in the definition file.

Here's a sample XML that defines three GCPs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<surveydata coordinatesystem="XYZ" description="Local coordinatesystem; meters" epsgcode="0">
 <markers>
   <marker id="0" name="1">
     <images>
       <image name="IMG_0138.JPG" xpixel="2051" ypixel="946"/>
       <image name="IMG_0139.JPG" xpixel="2030" ypixel="1366"/>
       <image name="IMG_0153.JPG" xpixel="2659" ypixel="57"/>
     </images>
     <gcp x="4.897" y="-18.174" z="-1.964" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="1" name="10">
     <images>
       <image name="IMG_0143.JPG" xpixel="2638" ypixel="1562"/>
       <image name="IMG_0153.JPG" xpixel="1996" ypixel="1515"/>
       <image name="IMG_0154.JPG" xpixel="1981" ypixel="1951"/>
     </images>
     <gcp x="10.017" y="-43.106" z="-1.121" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="2" name="11">
     <images>
       <image name="IMG_0127.JPG" xpixel="1774" ypixel="1441"/>
       <image name="IMG_0130.JPG" xpixel="1753" ypixel="2694"/>
       <image name="IMG_0132.JPG" xpixel="1288" ypixel="33"/>
       <image name="IMG_0133.JPG" xpixel="1435" ypixel="415"/>
     </images>
     <gcp x="-2.481" y="9.208" z="-1.922" checkpoint="false"/>
   </marker>
 </markers>
</surveydata>
```

A location should be defined as a GCP point. Check points (`checkpoint="true"`) can be used to validate the position of a reconstructed point against a known location. The deviation of each check point will be listed in the project report.

Do note that GCPs are only supported for *aerial* scenes (`scenetype=aerial` must be specified for the `POST /photoscene` endpoint).

Sub-pixel positions for `xpixel` and `ypixel` values are not supported.